# Change Bootstrap Popover Based on Condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

If the checkbox is checked, "Add to favorites" text should be shown. If the checkbox is unchecked "Remove from favorites" text should be shown.

**What i have tried:**

I tried to change the popover content attribute when the checkbox is checked. But this is not working.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/css/paperindex.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src=""></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input class="favorites-field desk-top-favorite-field" hidden id="favorites-check" type="checkbox">
  <label style="padding: 0;" data-content="Add to favorites" class="favorites-icon desk-top-favorite-icon ttip-top" for="favorites-check"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-heart"></i></label>
</div>
```

```js
$(".desk-top-favorite-icon").popover({
    placement: "top",
    trigger: "manual",
    container: 'body',
    html: true
  })
  .on("mouseenter", function() {
    var _this = this;
    $(this).popover("show");
    $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function() {
      $(_this).popover('hide');
    });
  }).on("mouseleave", function() {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
        $(_this).popover("hide");
      }
    }, 300);
  });

// Change the tooltip text based on checked & unchecked condition.
$(".desk-top-favorite-field").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).siblings('.desk-top-favorite-icon').prop('data-content', 'Add to <a href="#" class="link">favorites</a>');
  } else {
    $(this).siblings('.desk-top-favorite-icon').prop('data-content', 'Remove from <a href="#" class="link">favorites</a>');
  }
});
```

```css
.mrgn-top-50 {
  margin-top: 50px !important;
}

.mrgn-lft-50 {
  margin-left: 50px !important;
}

.favorites-icon i {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  background: #ffcc29;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #000;
}

.favorites-field:checked+label i {
  background: #1e6c97;
  color: #ffcc29;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="checkbox mrgn-lft-50 mrgn-top-50">
  <input class="favorites-field desk-top-favorite-field" hidden="" id="favorites-check" type="checkbox">
  <label style="padding: 0;" data-content="Add to <a href='#' class='link'>favorites</a>" class="favorites-icon desk-top-favorite-icon ttip-top" for="favorites-check" data-original-title="" title=""><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-heart"></i></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) rather than [prop()](https://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$(".desk-top-favorite-field").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).siblings('.desk-top-favorite-icon').attr('data-content', 'Add to <a href="#" class="link">favorites</a>');
  } else {
    $(this).siblings('.desk-top-favorite-icon').attr('data-content', 'Remove from <a href="#" class="link">favorites</a>');
  }
});
```

You also seem to have forgotten to add `data-toggle = "popover"` to your html, which is required to create a popover

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <input class="favorites-field desk-top-favorite-field" hidden id="favorites-check" type="checkbox">
  <label style="padding: 0;" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Add to favorites" class="favorites-icon desk-top-favorite-icon ttip-top" for="favorites-check"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-heart"></i></label>
</div>
```

I'm not 100% sure of your goal, but one thing I noticed is that the popover will not show once the checkbox is unchecked, and your code won't show the 'Add to' link. For popover to be always open, you can try adding this code:

```
$('.desk-top-favorite-icon')
    .popover('show')
    .off('click');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I found the solution for the issue & i have posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found solution by passing a function for bootstrap content property. In the function i'm returning the text based on conditions.

```js
$(".desk-top-favorite-icon").popover({
    content: function() {
      return ($(".desk-top-favorite-field").is(':checked')) ? 'Remove from <a href="#">Favorite Suppliers</a> list.' : 'Add to <a href="#">Favorite Suppliers</a> list.'
    },
    placement: "top",
    trigger: "manual",
    container: 'body',
    html: true
  })
  .on("mouseenter", function() {
    var _this = this;
    $(this).popover("show");
    $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function() {
      $(_this).popover('hide');
    });
  }).on("mouseleave", function() {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
        $(_this).popover("hide");
      }
    }, 300);
  });

// Change the tooltip text based on checked & unchecked condition.
$(".desk-top-favorite-field").on("change", function() {
  $('.desk-top-favorite-icon').popover('hide');
});
```

```css
.mrgn-top-50 {
  margin-top: 50px !important;
}

.mrgn-lft-50 {
  margin-left: 50px !important;
}

.favorites-icon i {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  background: #ffcc29;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #000;
}

.favorites-field:checked+label i {
  background: #1e6c97;
  color: #ffcc29;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.paperindex.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="checkbox mrgn-lft-50 mrgn-top-50">
  <input class="favorites-field desk-top-favorite-field" hidden="" id="favorites-check" type="checkbox">
  <label style="padding: 0;" class="favorites-icon desk-top-favorite-icon ttip-top" for="favorites-check" data-original-title="" title=""><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-heart"></i></label>
</div>
```